# What's the syntax of std::initializer_list:std::initializer_list<int>{(foo<T>,0)...}?

Tags: c++, std, initializer-list

I'm reading the code below which is about handling arbitrary form functions, and confused about the syntax in `initializer_list<int>{((get_arg<Tuple, I>(ds, t)), 0)...}` which seems to be treated as `initializer_list<int>{(void, 0)...}`, it seems `initializer_list` only take comma-separated parameters, why the tuple parameters work?

```
template<typename Tuple, std::size_t... I>
Tuple FunctionHandler::get_args(DataStream & ds, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    Tuple t;
    initializer_list<int>{((get_arg<Tuple, I>(ds, t)), 0)...};
    return t;
}

template<typename Tuple, std::size_t Id>
void FunctionHandler::get_arg(DataStream & ds, Tuple & t)
{
    ds >> std::get<Id>(t);
}
```

Add:
thanks for HolyBlackCat's comment, it's is related to the comma operator which I know very little about. Actually, it works fine with the syntax below:

```
int a = 1,2; // a is 1
int b = (1,2); // a is 2
```

so that in the code above the initializer_list will always take 0 to initialize its parameters.

Comment: Please explain how you come from `(get_arg<Tuple, I>(ds, t))` to `void`?

Comment: Due to the comma operator `get_arg<Tuple, I>(ds, t)), 0` results in just `0` being passed to the initialiser list

Comment: I'm not sure what you call "tuple parameters", but the expansion of `...` effectively produces a comma-separated list.

Comment: @273K, I don't think it is strictly correct, but I think the get_arg function returns void, so it seems to be understood like this.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i mean the ```get_arg<Tuple, I>(ds, t))``` and ```0``` forms a tuple

Comment: @AlanBirtles why it results 0 instead of the null variable that get_arg return?

Comment: @AlanBirtles i get it, int a = 1,2 results a = 1 and int a = (1,2) results a = 2. thanks a lot!